# modification table html display on page with php

Tags: php, html

I wanna try to modification my html table display content with PHP.

For Example i've got the result from mySQL query like below :

```
==================

id    |   date  | revenue

==================

01  | 26/09/2017 | 3000

02  | 26/09/2017 | 4000

01  | 27/09/2017 | 4000

==================
```

in my HTML+PHP pagination script i've set 5 row for each page.
So the result of the table will be same like this :

```
==================

id    |   date  | revenue

==================

01  | 26/09/2017 | 3000

02  | 26/09/2017 | 4000

01  | 27/09/2017 | 4000

=================
```

How if i wanna modification the display page to show only same date for each Page?

So the table that i want is similar like this :

**Page 1:**

```
==================

id    |   date  | revenue

==================

01  | 26/09/2017 | 3000

02  | 26/09/2017 | 4000


=================
```

**Page 2 :**

```
==================

id    |   date  | revenue

==================

01  | 27/09/2017 | 4000

=================
```

this is my script that i've tried:

```
<?php 

$REVENUE = 0;
$lastDate = '';
foreach($table_data as $row){
    $complete_date = $row['DATE'];
    $REVENUE = $REVENUE + $row['REVENUE'];
    if($complete_date != $lastDate){
        $lastDate = $complete_date;

    ?>
    <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['ID']?></td>
            <td><?php echo date("d/m/Y",strtotime($complete_date));?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['REVENUE']?$row['REVENUE']:0;?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    }
}
?>
```

but that's only make distinct the date like below :

```
 ==================

id    |   date  | revenue

==================

01  | 26/09/2017 | 3000
```

Please advice,

Comment: Hello & Welcome to Stackoverflow. We're here to help you with specific programming problems. Please show us what you've tried so far, share your thoughts with us and we'll help you. But nobody is going to write code for you. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: "How if i wanna modification the display page to show only 1 date for each Page?" With code. Have you tried to write any? If so, we can help you fix it. But it would also help if your example matched your requirement. Your example for that requirement has 2 dates on the first page, not 1, for instance

Comment: sorry i missed that one. i'm on progress to edit my post. thx for your response

Comment: hi @ADyson. sorry i mean the same date on each page. not 1 date. so sorry for this

Comment: Ah ok. Well for that surely you can just do a SQL query with the date you want in the WHERE clause? The browser can pass you the next date it wants when the user goes to next/previous page?

Answer (score 0):

```
$data_cek = $con->prepare("SELECT *  FROM tab1 ORDER BY nick DESC  LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset");
$data_cek->bindValue(':limit',(int)$pager_limit,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$data_cek->bindValue(':offset',(int)$pager_cur, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$data_cek -> execute();
$data_cek = $data_cek -> fetchAll();
```

example core My Php code and

parameters head

```
$pager_limit=10;$pager_cur=0;$pager_limit_g=$pager_limit;
if(isset($_GET["pager"])){
    $pager_cur=$_GET["pager"];
    $pager_cur=(int)$pager_limit+(int)$pager_cur;
}
```

calculation block

```
$adt=ceil($Max_count/$pager_limit);
if(!$adt<1){
print("<div class='w3-padding w3-margin'><center>");
echo "<a href='$global_href' class='btn btn-default'>1</a>";
for($i=1;$i<$adt;$i++){
    $ix=($i+1);
    if(!$i==1){$pager_cur=$i*$pager_limit_g;$pager_limit=$pager_limit_g;}
    $url=$global_href.'&pager='.$pager_cur.'&maxc='.$adt;
echo "<a href='$url' class='btn btn-default'>$ix</a>";
}}
echo "<a href='".$global_href."&all=1' class='btn btn-default'>(All)</a>";
print('</center></div>');
```

Comment: this algorithm so hard sensitive